# How to make mod_rewrite play nice with mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-wsgi

It looks like mod_rewrite is messing up mod_wsgi's env variables (scumbag eats SCRIPT_NAME or something).

Adding just this line:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

to my httpd.conf causes a problem in my Django based website. My alias looks like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /prefix /path/to/my/wsgi.py
```

Now both urls:

`example.com/prefix`and

`example.com/prefix/`

work (kinda.. the website shows up), but in the former case (without trailing slash), all urls are generated by django incorrectly, for example:

`example.com/some_url` instead of

`example.com/prefix/some_url`

If I comment out `#RewriteEngine On` the problem is gone, but I need mod_rewrite. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if apache error log spots anything, /etc/httpd/logs/error_log

Comment: Can't see anything relevant there.

Comment: And what are the actual rewrite rules you have elsewhere in your Apache configuration? I recollect seeing this issue reported once before but can't remember the outcome in that instance. Suggest you go search the mod_wsgi mailing list archives on Google Groups.

Comment: The thing is, I removed all rewrite conditions/rules, to narrow down the potential cause. Just "RewriteEngine On" directive is enough to cause the probem.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be a `[PT]` flag problem? In order to pass the redirected URI to `WSGIScriptAlias`, you need to add the PassThrough (PT) flag at the end of the rewrite rule, e.g.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^/external_url$   /internal_wsgi_url    [PT]
```

See [my answer on Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/57876/6377).